# Sum of Squares of odd numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I just wanted to know how we get from the first step to the next. I spent too much time on this but could not get to the next step. This seems a simple sum of squares of odd numbers but was not able to get the next step.

$$ \frac{2 \mathcal{E}_p}{M} \left(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \dots + (M-1)^2\right) $$
$$ \frac{2 \mathcal{E}_p}{M} \times \frac{M(M^2-1)}{6} $$

Comment: [Here's a mathjax tutorial.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What is $$E_p$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck check the edit history. I added the mathjax via edit.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Cause it was an image and I added exactly what was in the image

Comment: @TheGreatDuck This is not at all the issue with images, as everybody even moderately familiar with meta discussions knows. Why pretend being an expert in the rules of the site if this is to grossly misrepresent them?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Your innumerable recent comments pretending to edict the rules of the site only reveal deep misunderstandings. Let me suggest (with little hope to be heard, but...) that you turn to more productive (and less ridiculous, to be honest) interventions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), $$1^2+2^2+\cdots + (M-1)^2=\frac{(M-1)M(2M-1)}{6}$$
Since $M-1$ is odd, we must have $M-2$ even.  We now calculate, using the same formula,
$$2^2+4^2+\cdots+(M-2)^2=2^2(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(\frac{M-2}{2})^2)=2^2\frac{\frac{M-2}{2}\frac{M}{2}(M-1)}{6}=\frac{(M-2)M(M-1)}{6}$$

Subtract the sum of the even squares, from the sum of all the squares, to get
$$1^2+3^2+\cdots+(M-1)^2=\frac{(M-1)M(2M-1)}{6}-\frac{(M-2)M(M-1)}{6}=\frac{(M-1)M}{6}(2M-1-(M-2))=\frac{(M-1)M(M+1)}{6}=\frac{M(M^2-1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2m-1)^2
&=\sum_{r=1}^m (2r-1)^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^m \binom {2r-1}2+\binom {2r}2\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^{2m}\binom s2\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {2m+1}3}
\end{align}$$